# How can I convert this for loop to the dataframe?

Tags: python, for-loop, dataframe

If I use `print` ,I can `print` all datas.But when I use `data=` ,it just show me a value of `i=2917`. How can I convert this `for loop` to the dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('C:/Users/aaaa/Desktop/rrrrr/twstock/1101.xlsx')
for i in range (1,2917):
     data='{:.6%}'.format((df['close'][i]/df['close'][i-1])-1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You reassign `data` in every iteration of your for loop. There data contains only the value for `i = 2916`.

How about creating a list and then appending your data to it inside the for loop?

```
data = []
for i in range(1,2917):
    data.append('{:.6%}'.format((df['close'][i]/df['close'][i-1])-1))

print(data)
```

Comment: COOL！Thank you so much！

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using pandas vectorized methods for speed and cleanness:

```
df = pd.read_excel('C:/Users/aaaa/Desktop/rrrrr/twstock/1101.xlsx')
data = df["close"].pct_change()
```

Then you can change to a string representation list if desired by doing something like:

```
string_list = ['{:.6%}'.format(x) for x in data.tolist()[1:]]
```

Comment: data.tolist() is better.

Comment: I had always assumed they did the same under the hood, can you explain the difference? Or is it just for readability?

Comment: They're technically different. One feeds an iterable to `list`. The other is a Pandas method (which may or may not work the same way). But main reason it's more readable.

Answer (score 0):

DON'T loop through the dataframe like kalehmann suggested, it's very inefficient. You can either call `data = df["close"].pct_change()` as Sven suggested, or if you want to use a similar function to the one you defined:

```
data = df['first']/df['first'].shift(1)-1
```

And then you can run:

```
data_list = ['{:.6%}'.format(x) for x in data.tolist()]
```